# Unable to Run Pillow on python due to zlib

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-imaging-library, zlib

I am using Python 3.8.1 on Windows 10 and am trying to install Pillow.

I first ran:

```
pip install pillow
```

which it stated it worked in CMD. But when I went to Pycharm and wrote:

```
from PIL import image
```

it said that

> the module PIL doesn't exist.

So, I hopped onto Google and it stated that Pillow 7.0.0 needs zlib and jpeg. I tried disable both using:

```
pip install pillow --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="--disable-jpeg" --global-option="--disable-zlib"
```

It turned up the message saying I need Visual Studios 14.0 and now the error message is stating that zlib is needed. But at this point, I am unsure which zlib file to download and install. Also, when it is installed, what would I type to have python access it to allow me to use pillow?

Comment: Have you tried `from PIL import Image`? Note the capital I. Additionally have you tried running it from inside the interpreter? Open a command prompt. type `python`. Then try `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: @Axe319 I have just tried running ```from PIL import Image``` in both. I get the same message of: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' for Pycharm. But for the interpreter, it runs just fine. So, how would I get it to work on Pycharm?

Comment: The most likely cause is that Pycharm is using a different interpreter which does not have pillow installed. Look into how you can change which interpreter Pycharm is using.

Comment: @Axe319 So, I'm not sure if I did this right. I went and installed Pypy (says it was supported for 3.6, not sure if this implies 3.8 as well). I opened settings in Pycharm and went to Project interpreter. Click on the gear and add a new interpreter based on the path of pypy. Then I made a new file using the new interpreter. But running ```from PIL import Images``` still yields the same results: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: @AlexanderTang Which versions of python do you have installed now? sounds like you installed one from python.org (=3.8) and then installed `pypy`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I have 3.8.1 installed and I installed pypy after. But I was able to get it to work. I reinstalled Visual Studios and readded pillow, while running it with pypy. I'm not sure exactly which step I did that made it work.